# Chances of getting a 3 month or 6 months schengen visa?

Tags: visa, schengen

I am currently working in Ireland and I am not an EU passport holder. I have a GNIB card which is going be up for renewal on the 3rd o January 2020. I am planning to go to France on September 27-October 3 this year which falls just in time within the 3 month allowance before expiration the schenghen visa requires.The question is, how likely will be be given a 3 months or 6 months validity schenghen visa? or will they just probably give me 1 week?

Comment: It seems that they tend just to give the minimum validity and duration of stay required for the itinerary you submit with your application, especially if it is your first Schengen visa.  They're supposed to give you a few days' leeway to allow for minor changes of plan, but some countries do not do this.  I do not know what France does.